# NullPointerException while passing Audio Buffer to UDP

Tags: java, android

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    StreamAudioService(ContextWrapper).getSystemService(String) line: 386   
    StreamAudioService.getBroadcastAddress() line: 137  
    StreamAudioService.access$0(StreamAudioService) line: 135   
    StreamAudioService$UdpClient.run(byte[]) line: 102  
    StreamAudioService$UdpClient.write(byte[]) line: 95 
    StreamAudioService.write(byte[]) line: 64   
    StreamAudioService$PcmRecord$1.onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord) line: 343    
    AudioRecord$NativeEventHandler.handleMessage(Message) line: 745 
    AudioRecord$NativeEventHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99   
    Looper.loop() line: 137 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4424    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 817  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 584 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

This is my code :

```
private AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener updateListener = new AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (State.STOPPED == state) {
                Log.d(PcmRecord.this.getClass().getName(), "Recorder Stopped");
                return;
            }       

                audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                try {               

                            mService.write(buffer);
                            if(D) Log.i(TAG,"Push Buffer to UDP  : "+buffer.length);    


                            mOutputStream.write(buffer);        
                            if(D) Log.i(TAG,"Write Buffer to FILE: " + buffer.length);  

                }catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(PcmRecord.class.getName(),"Error occured in UPDATELISTENER, RECORDING ABORTED");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

//UDP Stream Threads

```
    /*
 * Stream Thread
 * 
 */

public class UdpClient extends Thread{

    public UdpClient(){
        super("STREAM AUDIO");
    }


    private static final int PORT = 2562;

    private DatagramPacket packet;

    private DatagramSocket mSocket;

    private InetAddress myBcastIP;


    public void write(byte[] out){
        run(out);
    }

    public void run(byte[] Buffer){

        try{        

            myBcastIP = getBroadcastAddress();

            Log.d(Tag,"My Bcast IP: "+myBcastIP);
            //myLocalIP = getLocalAddress();

            packet = new DatagramPacket(Buffer,Buffer.length,myBcastIP, PORT);

            mSocket.send(packet);

            Log.d(Tag,"Send Response: " + packet.getLength());

            Thread.sleep(20);

        }catch(InterruptedException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    catch(IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }           

    }   



}


//Get Broadcast Address

        private InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() throws IOException {

            WifiManager mWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

            WifiInfo info = mWifi.getConnectionInfo();

            Log.d(Tag,"\n\nWifi Status: "+ info.toString());


            DhcpInfo dhcp = mWifi.getDhcpInfo();

            if(dhcp == null) {

                Log.d(Tag,"Could not get dhcp info");

                return null;

            }

            int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;

            byte[] quads = new byte [4];

            for (int k=0 ; k < 4 ; k++)

                quads [k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);           

            return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
        }




//Play Thread


public class UdpServer extends Thread{

    public UdpServer(){
        super("Receiving Thread");
    }


    private static final int PORT = 2562;

    private DatagramSocket mSocket;

    private InetAddress myLocalIP;

    byte[] Buffer = new byte[2048];

    public void run(){
        try{

            myLocalIP = getLocalAddress();

            Log.d(Tag,"My Local IP: "+myLocalIP);


            mSocket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);

            mSocket.setBroadcast(true); 

            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(Buffer,Buffer.length);

            while(true){                


                mSocket.receive(packet);

                InetAddress remoteIP = packet.getAddress();

                if(remoteIP.equals(myLocalIP))
                    continue;

                byte[] data = packet.getData();

                Log.d(Tag,"Received Response : "+ data.length);

                Thread.sleep(25);

            }               

        }catch(InterruptedException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }catch(IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

    }

}




//Get Local Address


    private InetAddress getLocalAddress() throws IOException{

        try{

            for(Enumeration <NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();){

                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();

                for(Enumeration <InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();){

                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();

                    if(!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()){

                        return inetAddress;

                    }

                }

            }

        } catch (SocketException ex) {

            Log.e(Tag, ex.toString());

        }


        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Where is getSystemService() implemented?

Comment: Its in getBroadcastAddress()